# How to return an object from Mono SpringWebFlux more effective?

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am using Spring Webflux, and I need to return the object of Author from `Mono<Book>`, But I don’t know how to do it more correctly.

The method that should return `Author`:

```java
private Author getRegistredAuthor(Book bookInput) {
    String fullName = bookInput.getAuthor().getFullName();
    Optional<Author> optionalAuthor = repository.findByFullName(fullName).blockOptional();
    if(optionalAuthor.isPresent()){
        return optionalAuthor.get();
    }else {
        Author author = Author.builder().fullName(fullName).build();
        return repository.insert(author).block();
    }
}
```

The method that uses `Author` to create a new entity:

```java
public Mono<BookDto> create(@RequestBody Book book) {
    book.setAuthor(getRegistredAuthor(book));
    return bookRepository.insert(book)
            .map(BookDto::of);
}
```

As I understand it, if I use `block()`, I will greatly reduce the effectiveness of reactive.

Will it be more effective if I use so ?

```java
return repository.insert(author).blockOptional().get();
```

How would it be most efficient to return an object of `Author`?

Comment: Return `Mono<Author>`, don't block at all.

Comment: @123 I need ```Author```, because this method is used to create other entities

Comment: Then the other entity need to be made from the Mono. Either everything is reactive or it's pointless any of it being.

Comment: @123  But I do not understand how to do this. In other places I used ```.map (BookDto :: of)```, but I don’t know how this can be applied if I need not dto, but ```Book``` or ```Author``` itself

Comment: Just don't map it...

Comment: @NeverSleeps you could try to share the code where you want to use the author because it seems your real problem lies there.

Comment: @MartinTarjányi  I updated my question, please look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result, I solved my problem using Mono.zip. Maybe my solution will help someone too:

```java
    @PostMapping("/api/book")
    public Mono<BookDto> create(@RequestBody Book book) {
        return getObjectMono(book).flatMap(b -> bookRepository.insert(book))
                .map(BookDto::of);
    }


    private Mono<Object> getObjectMono(Book book) {
        return Mono.zip(
                getRegistredAuthor(book),
                getRegistredGenre(book)
        ).map(objects -> {
            book.setAuthor(objects.getT1());
            book.setGenre(objects.getT2());
            return book;
        });
    }

    private Mono<Genre> getRegistredGenre(Book bookInput) {
        String genreTitle = bookInput.getGenre().getTitle();
        return genreRepository.findByTitle(genreTitle)
                .switchIfEmpty(
                        genreRepository.insert(Genre.builder().title(genreTitle).build())
                );
    }

    private Mono<Author> getRegistredAuthor(Book bookInput) {
        String fullName = bookInput.getAuthor().getFullName();
        return authorRepository.findByFullName(fullName)
                .switchIfEmpty(
                        authorRepository.insert(Author.builder().fullName(fullName).build())
                );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do..

```
private Mono<Author> getRegistredAuthor(String fullName) {
    Mono<Author> optionalAuthor = repository.findByFullName(fullName); // .blockOptional();
    optionalAuthor
    .switchIfEmpty({
        Author author = Author.builder().fullName(fullName).build();
        return repository.insert(author).
    })
    .flatMap(author -> author);
}
```

Comment: I need to return the ```Author ```, because this method is used to create other entities

Comment: Ill suggest..return Mono<Author>, and at the places you are using this method use ```map``` or ```flatmap``` to get the Author object

Comment: It really looks like what I need, but I don’t understand how to do it. In other places I used ```.map (BookDto :: of)```, but I don’t know how this can be applied if I need not dto, but ```Book``` or ```Author``` itself